# static struct member gets “undefined reference”. Don't know why

Tags: c++, static, struct, undefined-reference

I want to create a class that collects information from many other classes and the end of a simulation. For that, it has to be independent from all other classes and completely accessible. For that I chose a static approach, a static struct indeed.

This is my Foo.h

```
class Foo
{
 public:
   static int app_counter;

   typedef struct
   {
       double eed;
       int bits;  
   }APPLayer;

   static APPLayer applayer_metric;
public:
   Foo(){};
   ~Foo();
};
```

This is the Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"
int Foo::app_counter=0;
//How do I set all internal members to zero?
Foo::APPLayer applayer_metric;
Foo::~Foo()
{
  std::cout << app_counter << std::endl; 
  //Which is the way to access to the values of my members?
  std::cout << applayer_metric.bits << std::endl;
}
```

This is the error I get in my Foo.CPP

> Foo.cc:38: undefined reference to `Foo::applayer_metric'

If for instance I change the line in Foo.cpp to this one

> std::cout << Foo::applayer_metric.bits << std::endl;

I get exactly the same error.

My questions are:

1. How can I initialize all members of a static struct variable to zero?
2. How do I access to these members in other functions in Foo.cpp?

FYI, there is no complain if I initialize and access the variable "app_counter"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ undefined reference to to static member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110487/c-undefined-reference-to-to-static-member)

Comment: You have a trailing `e` in `int Foo::app_counter=0;e`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does it mean to have an undefined reference to a static member?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092765/what-does-it-mean-to-have-an-undefined-reference-to-a-static-member)

Comment: @PlasmaHH it is not a duplicate because I define and declare the struct. I want to initialize them.
The typo 'e' is now corrected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of `Foo::applayer_metric` is missing a scope resolution operator. Change it to this:

```
Foo::APPLayer Foo::applayer_metric;
```

Comment: sorry for the last comment. It was a typo. I think this was the last option to test! Now I can initialize the struct at the constructor, thanks a lot. I am reading your post, if I could have found it, I would have not posted this question here. :)