# Qt C++ Initializing Class and Calling method w/ Variable from Class

Tags: c++, qt

Basically I have a class that has multiple QString values, a constructor, and a method. The object gets it's 'values' set in the constructor. Then I need to call the method, `toString()` using the object to return the assigned value. How can I do this as when I try I get `invalid use of non-static data member 'DisconnectReason::BANNED'`. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Class:

```
class DisconnectReason
{
public:
    QString BANNED = "B&";
    QString IDLE_TIMEOUT = "it";
    QString KICKED = "k";
    QString MANUAL = "man";
    QString PING_TIMEOUT = "pt";
    QString reason;
    DisconnectReason(const QString reason)
    {
        this->reason = reason;
    }
public:
    virtual QString toString()
    {
        return reason;
    }
};
```

Interface.cpp

```
#include "interface.h"
#include "ui_interface.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include "constants.h"

Interface::Interface(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Interface)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    DisconnectReason *dr = new DisconnectReason(DisconnectReason::BANNED);//Error here
    qDebug() << dr->toString();
}

Interface::~Interface()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Seems like the error is perfectly clear -- that QString isn't declared as static, but you're trying to use it as though it were. Either you need to instantiate an instance of the DisconnectReason class and get the string from there, or make that QString static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `BANNED` variable (and others) is declared as a non-static member, you can't use it like `DisconnectReason::BANNED`. Only [static members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) can be used like that.

There's two options:

- Declaring those variables as static members
- Using integral `enum` and assign them their strings in `toString` method.

---

#### Declaring static

```
class DisconnectReason
{
public:
    static const QString BANNED;
    /* others */

    DisconnectReason(const QString &reason)
    {
        this->reason = reason;
    }

    virtual QString toString()
    {
        return reason;
    }
};

// .cpp
const QString DisconnectReason::BANNED = "B&";
/* others */
```

As it's shown above, you can't initialize those variables in-class. You should instead initialize them out-side of your class (in a `.cpp` file), like what I've done. (Only [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) expressions can be used as in-class initialization of static members)

This way, using `DisconnectReason::BANNED` is perfectly valid.

#### Using `enum`

```
class DisconnectReason
{
public:
    enum Reasons {
        BANNED,
        /* others */
    };

    DisconnectReason(const Reasons reason)
    {
        this->reason = reason;
    }

    virtual QString toString()
    {
        if(this->reason == BANNED){
            return "B&";
        }
        return "Unknown Reason";
    }
};
```

Comment: This looks very promising. Thank you, I will try when I get home!

Comment: This works very well. However, I have a `Constants.cpp` that has a Contructor for the Class: `Constants`. When I get a variable from this it says `undefined reference to 'DisconnectReason::BANNED'`

Comment: @NicholasJohnson `static` members should be _defined_ in a `.cpp` file. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/undefined-reference-to-static-class-member) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110487/undefined-reference-to-a-static-member).

Comment: So no variable declaration at all in the .h?

Comment: @NicholasJohnson edited my answer.  `QString DisconnectReason::BANNED = "B&";` should be in a `.cpp`.

Comment: I would *also* recommend `const` on top of `static`. A constant should be `const`, you don't want to accidentally assign to it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You're absolutely right. All constants should be `const`. Edited my answer.