# undefined reference to static members quint64/QMutex in separate classes

Tags: c++, qt, static-members, undefined-reference

I have a few classes giving this strange undefined reference problem. Here are two examples to start off with :

**backupmanager.h**

```
class BackupManager : public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT
    const QString TAG = QString("BackupManager"); 

    public:
        //...
    signals:
        //...
    public slots:
        //...
    private:
        // Intermediatory storage map for file information
        static quint64 bytesSavedDedulication;          <-------------- static member
        static quint64 bytesSavedLocalDuplication;      <-------------- static member
        static quint64 bytesSavedGlobalDuplication;     <-------------- static member
        static quint64 numberOfFilesShouldBeCopied;     <-------------- static member
        //...
}
```

**backupmanager.cpp**

```
//...
path\to\project\libs\backupmanager.cpp:720: error: undefined reference to `BackupManager::bytesSavedLocalLock'
path\to\project\libs\backupmanager.cpp:721: error: undefined reference to `BackupManager::bytesSavedLocalDuplication'
//...
```

and another example

**DatabaseManager.h**

```
class DatabaseManager {

    //...
    private:
       // Mutex preventing concurrent access
       static QMutex dbLock;               <-------------notice that it is static
    //...
}
```

**DatabaseManager.cpp**

```
path\to\project\libs\databasemanager.cpp:431: error: undefined reference to `DatabaseManager::dbLock'
```

The **static members** give the **undefined reference** when attempting to access them in code, as you see in the cpp line references.

From experience, I know that an undefined reference usually means a method declaration in the header file has no definition, but this is a problem which I have not yet run into before.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110487/undefined-reference-to-a-static-member) post suggests attempting to defined the member. Doing this for `static quint64 bytesSavedDedulication;`:

```
static quint64 bytesSavedDedulication = 0;
```

gives the following error:

```
path\to\project\libs\backupmanager.h:312: error: non-const static data member must be initialized out of line
```

**What could cause this problem?**

*(if more information is required, please let me know - would be happy to provide it)*

Comment: Have you tried `quint64 BackupManager::bytesSavedDedulication = 0;` in the .cpp file?

Comment: @dxiv so that works, but it is local only to that class - so getters & setters won't work with it...right?

Comment: You declared it as a static private member, if that's what you mean by "*local only to that class*". You *can* write getters and setters for private members, though not sure I follow that part of the question.

Comment: Just a common C++ question? If so then you need to initialize those static data member like `quint64 BackupManager::bytesSavedLocalDuplication = 0;` in backupmanager.cpp.