# static constexpr array in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following, I would like to define valid neighbours as a class member attribute:

```
struct Chessboard
{ 
    ...

    vector<vector<Cell>> cells;

    static int constexpr neighbours[][2] = {
         {-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1},
         {0, -1},  {0, 0},  {0, 1},
         {1, 1},   {1, 0},  {1, 1}
    };

    bool isNeighbour() {
        for (int row = 0; row < nRows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < nCols; col++) {
                for (const int *d : neighbours) { // <---- Error!
                    if (cells[row][col].isMagic) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, I get an `undefined reference to` Chessboard::neighbours` during the link process.

What would be the correct way of doing it?

Looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110487/undefined-reference-to-a-static-member) it seems static members should be declared inside the `.cpp` file, but in my case, I get the exact same behaviour.

For instance, in Python I can declare static members inside my class. Why isn't allowed in C++?

Comment: You have to declare it inside the `struct Chessboard` and define it outside.

Comment: You still need a definition of `neighbours` somewhere outside of your class.

Comment: Isn't possible to have a static class member the same as in Python?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why both? How can I get a SSOT?

Comment: @nowox _"Why both?"_  Because its required by the compiler. Alternatively you may add `inline`, if you have c++17. Whatever a _"SSOT"_ means, examples can be found in the duplicate.