# how to use other static members in static member function -- C++

Tags: c++

below I have a class

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Car
{

public:
static int b;


static char* x1(int x)
{
    b=x;
    return (char *)"done";
}

};
```

in main

```
int main()
{
    char* ret = Car::x1(42);
    for(int x=0;x<4;x++)
    {cout<<ret[x]<<endl;}
  
    return 0;
}
```

but I am getting following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccRfvgz8.o: warning: relocation against `_ZN3Car1bE' in read-only section `.text._ZN3Car2x1Ei[_ZN3Car2x1Ei]'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccRfvgz8.o: in function `Car::x1(int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3Car2x1Ei[_ZN3Car2x1Ei]+0xc): undefined reference to `Car::b'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Update**

after the comment by Serge Balesta I changed x1 function to include         `Car::b=x;` but I get this error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccjMKe4u.o: warning: relocation against `_ZN3Car1bE' in read-only section `.text._ZN3Car2x1Ei[_ZN3Car2x1Ei]'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccjMKe4u.o: in function `Car::x1(int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3Car2x1Ei[_ZN3Car2x1Ei]+0xc): undefined reference to `Car::b'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

updated function

```
static char* x1(int x)
{
    Car::b=x;
    return (char *)"done";
}
```

Comment: In C++ string literals are a `const char *`. They are ***not*** a `char *`, and casting them to a `char *` does not fix this bug.

Comment: You need a proper *definition* for static members. Here you should add `int Car::b;` just before `main`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta see the question update after I add what u said. now different error

Comment: You have to define a static duration object: its definition must occur at file level outside of any function: `...` `int Car::b;` `int main() {...`

Comment: @SergeBallesta Can u please explain it in English. Or u think I know all these "duration object" and etc.

Comment: If you want to learn C++, you will have to learn those terms ;-) . Static duration if for *something* (what I call an object) which will last for the whole program. That is variables declared at file level (outside of any function) **and static members of classes**. Long story made short, a *static member* has to be defined at file level and not inside a function.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks for ur very helpful and detailed comment. But can u please add that in my question and please if u can show me how it's done. I am new to c++ but I am some level of good in C

Comment: Just write `int Car::b;` exactly one line above `int main()`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta and where the declaration will go?

Comment: I have written a full code example as an [additional anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68195380/3545273) to the duplicate.