# Examining static const class members in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

How can I print the value of `static const` class members in gdb?

Say I have:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    static const int bar = 5;
};

int main() { 
    std::cout << foo::bar;
    return 0; 
}
```

How do I examine the contents `foo::bar` in gdb?

I tried:

```
(gdb) p foo::bar
No symbol "foo" in current context.
(gdb) p 'foo::bar'
No symbol "foo::bar" in current context.
```

Comment: Could be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110487/undefined-reference-to-a-static-member).  If you add a definition or make it inline, does it work then?

Comment: Hmm, not even if I add a constructor and set a breakpoint in it does it think that `bar` or `foo::bar` exists in the current context.

Comment: It could well be that you can not. Such name doesn't have linkage, and `gdb` so it doesn't exist as a symbol for `gdb`. And `gdb` is not a compiler, so it can not extract this information from the C++ code itself. It is just a limitation of the toolchain.

Comment: @TedLyngmo no instance was created, why would it think otherwise? it would inline the value of static member, that's all.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I added a constructor and set a breakpoint in it and created an instance to see if that would help - it did not.

Comment: Have you checked the disassembly for `main`? The code would be optimized, then the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: ODR-use `bar` might help.

Comment: If I add an instance of `foo`, then `p foo::bar` works for me in gdb.

Comment: @ssbssa - you're right. If I just do `foo f;` as the first line of `main()` I'm able to print the value of it. Even though `-O0` is passed, I'm wondering if GCC is still doing a slight optimization by not creating a symbol if an instance is never created.

Answer (score 1):

You can't because gcc does not resolve this to a symbol but to an actual value in the assembly so gdb has nothing to look at. If you needed to you might be able to add the `volatile` keyword to prevent the compiler from performing this optimization.

Answer (score 0):

As @ssbssa pointed out, as long as one instance of the class is created, it works. Doesn't matter where, instance could even be created in an unused function. For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    static const int bar = 5;
};

void unused() {
    foo f;
}

int main() { 
    return 0; 
}
```

And in gdb:

```
gdb) info variables
All defined variables:
...
File test.cpp:
4:  const int foo::bar;
...
(gdb) p foo::bar
$1 = 5
```

You can see that as long as there is one instance of foo somewhere, there is a symbol for it in `.debug_info` section of the binary, i.e.:

```
user@krypton:~$ readelf -w a.out | grep foo
    <28ee>   DW_AT_name        : foo
    <2901>   DW_AT_linkage_name: (indirect string, offset: 0xcfa): _ZN3foo3barE
```

Note that the same symbol is missing if the compiler detects that no instances of the class are ever created. Seems to be some quirk/optimization of GCC that can't be disabled.