# Why static global variables initialized to zero, but static member variable in class not initialized?

Tags: c++

`static int counter // will initalized to 0`

but if I make that variable inside a class, it's not initialized and I have to initialize it outside of class

```
class Test {
static int counter;  // not initialized
};
...
Test::counter = 0;
```

I know the static variables are stored in BSS segment in memory and initialized by default to 0, so why is it when I make a static in class not initialized?

Comment: Because the declaration inside the class is not a definition.

Comment: Also the out of class definition `Test::counter = 0;` is incorrect. It should instead be `int Test::counter = 0;`

Comment: so anything inside the class, it's just a declaration to the compiler and does not take any space in memory before we instantiate it. That's right? @Jason Laim

Comment: Because C++ is weird like this. Use `inline static int counter = 0;` instead.

Comment: @Run Not "anything" inside the class but only for non-inline "static" data member

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why static global variables initialized to zero, but static member variable in class not initialized?

Because the ***declaration*** for a *non-inline static data member* inside the class is **not a definition**.

This can be seen from [static data member documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Explanation):

> The static keyword is only used with the **declaration** of a static member, inside the class definition, but not with the definition of that static member. **The declaration inside the class body is not a definition** and may declare the member to be of incomplete type (other than void), including the type in which the member is declared:

---

Also the out of class definition `Test::counter = 0;` is incorrect. It should instead be `int Test::counter = 0;`

Answer (score 4):

The question is based on a false premise. Static member variables are subject to zero initialization. The following code would perform the expected zero initialization of `counter`.

```cpp
class Test {
static int counter;  // declaration, not defined yet
};

int Test::counter;   // definition with zero-initialization
```

It's not the initialization that is required, but the definition. Without the definition, the compiler has no place in which to perform the initialization, zero or otherwise.

See also [Undefined reference to a static member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110487/) and [Defining static members in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536372/defining-static-members-in-c) for more background information.