# I can't use a static std::queue?

Tags: c++, static-members

I would like to use a `static std::queue` (`static std::queue<Efeito*> efeitos;`) to be called in my static functions in the same class, but I tried several ways and the one thing I got is a error:

> `undefined reference to EfeitosVisuais::efeitos'`

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include "Efeito.h"
#include "Efeitos Visuais/EfeitoPedregulho.h"


class EfeitosVisuais {
public:
    static std::queue<Efeito*> efeitos;
    static void AddEfeito(double x, double y,char efeito){
        switch(efeito){
            case 'P':
                EfeitoPedregulho *pedregulho = new EfeitoPedregulho(x,y);
                efeitos.push(pedregulho);
                break;
        }
    }

    static void Atualizar(int tempodejogo) {
        if(!efeitos.empty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < efeitos.size(); i++) {
                efeitos.front()->Atualiza(tempodejogo);
                efeitos.push(efeitos.front());
                efeitos.pop();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Where did you define `std::queue<Efeito*> EfeitosVisuais::efeitos;` ? It has to be  *somewhere*. As it is not an instance member, its formal definition must appear in with static linkage *once* in some translation unit, pretty much exactly as I just showed, outside the class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undefined reference to Base::object linker error @ c++ w/ freeglut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074073/undefined-reference-to-baseobject-linker-error-c-w-freeglut)

Comment: since C++17 add `inline` to the declaration

Answer (score 3):

`static` data members needs to be defined separately. Just define your static variable outside the class in the `.cpp` file:

```cpp
std::queue<Efeito*> EfeitosVisuais::efeitos;
```

**Update**

As @Remy Lebeau said in the comments, The variable *must have* exactly one definition so that it doesn't violate [ODR - One definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition). This is why it is important that you define it in the `.cpp` file because if it's in the `.h` file, the header file may be included in multiple places which will result in an error.

As @WBuck said,
Since **c++17** you can use [inline variables.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static):

```cpp
inline std::queue<Efeito*> efeitos;
```

Also note that if you use `constexpr`, the variable is implicitly `inline`.

Comment: "*Just define your static variable outside the class*" - this is not good enough on its own. For instance, defining it after the class declaration in the same header file would be bad. It is important to define it someplace where it will be seen only one time, such as in a cpp file.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thats true unless they specify `inline` (and they're using `C++17`)

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks, I added this to the answer